# How can I automatically update TextField in swiftUI

Tags: timer, swiftui, textfield

I'm new in swiftUI developing, and I have a little problem. I made a function using Timer to create a count up timer. I want to display the time updating in a TextField, but it doesn't work (with a Text it works). Here is the code:

```
 import SwiftUI
  struct ContentView: View {

    @State var min: Int = 0
    @State var sec: Int = 0
    @State var time = ""
    @State var timer: Timer? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        VStack{
            TextField("Tempo (min o mm:ss)", text: $time)
            
        HStack{

            Button(action: {
                self.start()
                self.time = String(self.min)+":"+String(self.sec)
                
            }){
                Text("Start")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.stop()
                
            }){
                Text("Stop")
            }
        }
      }//VStack
     }//NavigationView
    }//body
    func start(){
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){
                temp in
                self.sec = self.sec + 1
                if(self.sec == 59){
                    self.sec = 0
                    self.min = self.min + 1
                }
            }
        }
        
    func stop(){
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }

   }//contetView
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the change because you're not updating the `time` String in your timer loop.

Here's the fix:

```
func updateTimeString() {
    self.time = String(format: "%02d:%02d", self.min, self.sec)
}

func start(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { temp in
        self.sec = self.sec + 1
        if self.sec == 59 {
            self.sec = 0
            self.min = self.min + 1
        }
        updateTimeString()
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I moved the code to set the `time` string to a separate function.  You can then call this from your `Button` as well.
- I used `String(format:)` to add formatting to your string to show 2 digits for the minutes and seconds.